# Timezone in time object in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone

I can create time object with particular timezone

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone 

EST_TZ = timezone('US/Eastern')

datetime.time(19,20,1,tzinfo = EST_TZ)
```

Output:

```
datetime.time(19, 20, 1, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
```

but when I extract time from datetime object the timezone is lost:

```
current_date = datetime.datetime.now(EST_TZ)
current_date.time()
```

Output

```
datetime.time(12, 28, 54, 509380)
```

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

P.S. later on I need to compute time delta, but it is not working because one object is time aware and the other is not.

Comment: Time zone rules depend on dates, so why would you want to have time only, with a time zone?

Comment: @FObersteiner, I guess I don't, I am curious why `datetime.time(19,20,1,tzinfo = EST_TZ)` allows timezone in time object?

Comment: Not sure, maybe the technical possibility to have this is a remnant of when there were no timezone libraries (it took until Python3.9 for that to be part of the standard library!), and timezone just meant "UTC offset" - which is *ok* to have without a date?